# Calculating the Energy Stored in an Inductor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The [energy stored in an inductor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqQ3-d0V4D0&feature=youtu.be) has been derived from the following formulae;

$P = iL\frac{di}{dt}$ (1)

$P = \frac{dE}{dt}$ (2)

Substituting eq. (1) into eq. (2).

$\frac{dE}{dt} = iL\frac{di}{dt}$ (3)

How do I remove the $dt$ term on both sides of the equation?

Basically how do I get to the next step which is? And what should be the limits on the right hand side of the equation?

$\int_0^iiLdi=\int dE$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have for an inductor:

$$\text{U}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\text{L}\cdot\text{I}'_\text{L}\left(t\right)\tag1$$

Now, for the energy we have:

$$\text{E}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\int\text{P}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\int\text{U}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\int\text{L}\cdot\text{I}'_\text{L}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\tag2$$

Now, substitute $\text{u}=\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)$:

$$\int\text{L}\cdot\text{I}'_\text{L}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\text{L}\int\text{u}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\text{L}\cdot\frac{\text{u}^2}{2}+\text{K}=\text{L}\cdot\frac{\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)^2}{2}+\text{K}\tag3$$

Comment: May I ask what happened to the $I'_L(t)$ in line (3) when you substituted $u = I_L(t)$?

Comment: Yes, what do you get when you take the derivative of the current with repect to t?

Comment: Is it because $I'_L(t) = \frac{dI_L(t)}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(I_L(t))=1$?

Comment: No, why is the derivative equal to 1 that is wrong for a general currentfunction

Comment: Is it allowed to cancel the dt term? $\int{L{\cdot}I_L(t){\cdot}I'_L(t)\;dt}=\int{L{\cdot}I_L(t){\cdot}\frac{dI_L(t)}{dt}\;dt}=L\int{I_L(t)dI_L(t)}=L\int{u}\;du$

Answer (score 0):

You have instantaneous power $P(t) = L i(t) \frac{\mathrm{d} i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}$. To get to the energy you need to integrate this $P(t)$, i.e. $E = \int_0^t P(t) \mathrm{d} t = L \int_0^{I} i' \mathrm{d} i' = \frac{1}{2} L I^2$.

Going back to your formulas, you just first derive $E = \int P(t) \mathrm{d} t$ from your equation (2) and then plug (1) into it.